# How do I concatenate corresponding rows of multiple ndarrays and create new matrices on the fly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

Suppose I have 5 ndarrays like:

```
In [2]: A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: B = np.array([[5, 6] , [7, 8]])

In [4]: C = np.array([[9, 10] , [11, 12]])

In [5]: D = np.array([[13, 14] , [15, 16]])

In [6]: E = np.array([[17, 18] , [19, 20]])

In [7]: A
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [8]: B
Out[8]: 
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In [9]: C
Out[9]: 
array([[ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])

In [10]: D
Out[10]: 
array([[13, 14],
       [15, 16]])

In [11]: E
Out[11]: 
array([[17, 18],
       [19, 20]])
```

If I want to concatenate the corresponding rows and create matrices F and G on the fly:

```
In [13]: F
Out[13]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10],
       [13, 14],
       [17, 18]])

In [15]: G
Out[15]: 
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 7,  8],
       [11, 12],
       [15, 16],
       [19, 20]])
```

without pre-initializing F and G, what would be the efficient way to implement this? I have large datasets that needs this operation plus creating new matrices while looping, and was not sure what would be the best way to implement this in Python with minimal cost.

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack) function to build numpy array from smaller pieces

```
lst = [A, B, C, D, E]
num_rows = A.shape[0]
res = []
for i in range(num_rows):
    rows = [x[i] for x in lst]
    r = np.vstack(rows)
    res.append(r)
```

One line version of the same

```
num_rows = A.shape[0]
[np.vstack(map(lambda x: x[i], lst)) for i in range(num_rows)]
```